# SWIFT - Trouble to reload tableView data

Tags: swift, uitableview

I will tell what is happening with my tableView, and what should happen

In **Screen 1** I fetch data form API and send to a tableView on Screen 2.

On **Screen 2** tableView I display an array of objects each one in one cell.

When I click on cell "X" I display a **3rd screen** with some specific data for "X".

Ok, till now, everything works fine!

Then when I come back to tableView on **2nd screen** and click on cell "Y" the 3rd Screen display "X" data

If I start with cell "y", the 3rd screen get stuck with "X" data and do not show "Y" data

I want that my 3rd screen get reset when I come back to 2nd screen

sorry about my english, I am working to improve and Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

[This is my 2nd screen didSelectRow function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LUqV.png)

[This is my 3rd screen where i get new object from 2nd screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnR4d.png)

This is for a job application, my first one
Ty s2 s2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line number 75 with

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(descricaoVC, animated: true)
```

with

```
let newDescricaoVC = DescricaoVC() // initialise your view controller from storyboard/ xib or whatever logic you implemented.
newDescricaoVC.oficina = oficinasArray[indexPath.row]
navigationController?.pushViewController(newDescricaoVC, animated: true)
```

[UPDATE]

You are pushing same VC always thats y it do not get refreshed.
Either you can create new VC and push like I showed you in this answer, or if you want to save VC in memory then add viewDidAppear function in your 3rd screen and move your code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear

Comment: Ty so much, love you